# Enable button if all select options have been changed from default option

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7

I am trying to develop code so that a user is unable to click a button unless all select fields have changed.

So far, I have been able to make the code work if one select field has changed, however, the button should only work if all select fields have changed.

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $btnNext2 = $('button.cf7mls_next');
    let $choice = $('#select2-restructuring-one-02-container')
    var $option = $("option:contains('Please select an option')");
    var $btnNext2 = $('button.cf7mls_next');
    $option.attr('disabled', true)
    $btnNext2.attr('disabled', true);

    $(".test").change(function() {
      $btnNext2.attr('disabled', false);
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Could you also post the code for the select button?

Comment: It's a little unclear, because if your `<select class='text'>` has two options and the user "changes" from option 1 to opt 2, then "changes" back from opt 2 to opt 1, the slelect has *not* been changed from the default option - but your code ("working for one select") will still leave the button enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned in the original question that if the user changes the option, option 1 is disabled so the user can't select that again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with `select` change event.. Here's an example

```js
$('select.myselect').on('change' , function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('changed');
  if($('select.changed').length === $('select.myselect').length){
    console.log("All Select Changed");
    $("button").prop("disabled" , false);
  }else{
    console.log("One or More not selected yet!!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="myselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select class="myselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select class="myselect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<button disabled>Submit</button>
```

**The Idea Is:** To add new class called `changed` to the changed select then count number of changed select and comapre it with our presented select